# Как сделать таймер, который сработает через пару месяцев?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, qt

Есть задача ставить таймер, который сработает через пару месяцев. Столкнулся с проблемой у `QTimer::start(int msec)` время указывается в int так еще и в миллисекундах. Получается я могу указать 2147483647 миллисекунд, а это чуть меньше месяца. Раньше пользовался `crontab`, но от него пришлось отказаться.

Пример кода:

```
uint sec_prediction, sec_now, answer;

QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
sec_now = now.toTime_t();
QLocale mylocale(QLocale::English);
qDebug() << mylocale.toString(now, "MMM d hh:mm:ss") << sec_now;

QDateTime payment = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
payment = payment.addMonths(3);
sec_prediction = payment.toTime_t();
qDebug() << mylocale.toString(payment, "MMM d hh:mm:ss") << sec_prediction;

answer = sec_prediction - sec_now;
qDebug() << answer;

QTimer timer;
timer.setSingleShot(true);
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processQueue()));
timer.start(answer * 1000);
```

Вывод консоли:

```
"Jan 7 00:42:38" 1673041358
"Apr 7 00:42:38" 1680817358
7776000  - After this time, the timer should start.

QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot have negative intervals
```

Я использую Qt 4.8, C++98
Признателен за помощь

Comment: Вы можете сделать таймер, который запустит другой таймер. И так до тех пор пока не наберёте нужный интервал. Другой вопрос, что у вас за машина и приложение что они поддерживают многомесячные аптаймы. Если сроки так велики, нужна служба, которая будет хранить таймеры не диске.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy костылить не очень хочется. Серверное приложение, которое занимается планированием

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/at-command-in-linux/

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy к сожалению мне нужно решить задачу при помощи qt и с++

Comment: Но тогда запишите времена и команды на диск. В приложение вставьте регулярный таймер. Когда время до ближайшего события станет не большим, создайте для него специальный таймер. Так вы сможете хотя бы перезапускать вашу программу не теряя данные.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy эти данные есть в базе. На крайний вариант, можно запускать раз в день таймер и проверять возможна ли планировка в миллисекундах

Comment: @roman-khudoberdin Я могу добавить, что к регулярному таймеру еще нужно добавить проверку времени currentDateTime. Потому что любой таймер накапливает ошибку. Заранее вычислить время, в которое должно произойти событие, а затем на каждом срабатывании дискретного таймера сравнивать текущее время с запланированным.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь планировщиком задач операционной системы